# When clicking country picker inside adapter class getting crashed java.lang.ClassCastException:

Tags: java, android

When clicking the country picker inside adapter class getting crashed  showing                                                                         `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sunday.holiday.com.teller.DemoApplication cannot be cast to android.app.Activity`.

**Here's my code:**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyView> {
    String date1,date;

    public static List<previousModel> list;
    Context context1;
    public static ArrayList<QualificationModel1> list_n= new ArrayList<QualificationModel1>();

    public class MyView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public EditText edt_qual,edt_position,edt_cntry,edt_from_date1,edt_to_date1,edt_experince1,edt_comapny_name;
        TextView dumy_to,dummy_frm,curntly,txt_compname;
        Switch switchButton;
        CountryPicker picker1;

        public MyView(View view) {
            super(view);//
            dummy_frm = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dumy_frm);
            txt_compname= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_compname);
            dumy_to = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dumy_to);
            edt_from_date1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_from_date1);
            edt_to_date1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_to_date1);
            curntly= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.curntly);
            switchButton = (Switch)view. findViewById(R.id.switchButton2);

            edt_comapny_name=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.edt_comapny_name);
            edt_position=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_position);
            edt_cntry=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_cntry);
            edt_experince1=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_experince1);

            switchButton.setChecked(false);
            switchButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean bChecked) {
                    if (bChecked) {
                        curntly.setText("Currently Working");
                    } else {
                        curntly.setText("Currently not Working");
                    }
                }
            });

            edt_from_date1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (!((Activity) context1).isFinishing()) {

                        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                        int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                        int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                        DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(context1, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                date1 = String.valueOf(dayOfMonth) + "/" + String.valueOf(monthOfYear + 1)
                                        + "/" + String.valueOf(year);
                                edt_from_date1.setText(date1);
                                dummy_frm.setText(date1);
                            }

                        }, yy, mm, dd);
                        datePicker.show();
                    }

                }
            });

           edt_to_date1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (!((Activity) context1).isFinishing()) {

                        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                        int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                        int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                        DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(context1, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                date = String.valueOf(dayOfMonth) + "/" + String.valueOf(monthOfYear + 1)
                                        + "/" + String.valueOf(year);
                                edt_to_date1.setText(date);
                                dumy_to.setText(date);
                            }
                        }, yy, mm, dd);
                        datePicker.show();
                    }
                }
            });
            picker1 = CountryPicker.newInstance("Select Country");  // dialog title
            picker1.setListener(new CountryPickerListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSelectCountry(String name, String code, String dialCode, int flagDrawableResID) {

                    edt_cntry.setText(name);
                    picker1.dismiss();
                }
            });
            edt_cntry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (!((Activity) context1).isFinishing()) {
                        picker1.show(((ForumActivity) context1).getSupportFragmentManager(), "COUNTRY_PICKER");
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }


    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<previousModel> horizontalList,Context context) {
        this.list = horizontalList;
        this.context1=context;
    }

    @Override
    public MyView onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.previous_work_layout, parent, false);
        return new MyView(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyView holder, final int position) {
        int k=position+1;


        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: your `context1` is not an activity, it is an `Application`. Check how you create your `RecyclerViewAdapter`

Comment: com.sunday.holiday.com.teller.DemoApplication can u post this code??

Answer (score 0):

Your `CountryPicker` is not initialized. Before setting title initialize like below.

`picker1 = new DatePickerDialog(pass context,...);`

`picker1 = CountryPicker.newInstance("Select Country");`